# Finding multiple attribute from GROUP BY function in a Query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table like this

```
1   Mo1 4
2   Mo7 2
3   Mo3 2
4   Mo2 2
5   Mo9 2
6   Mo8 1
7   Mo6 1
8   Mo4 1
```

I have got above results using

```
select movie_id, count(*) cnt from review Group by movie_id order by cnt desc
```

however if i want to list all movie_id for which cnt>1 my query fails.

Is there any way to get the results as desired ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select movie_id, count(*) cnt 
from review 
Group by movie_id 
Having count(*)>1
order by cnt desc
```

Comment: this is really funny: when I posted my response i got an error like: this is a duplicate of [your response] :) (I posted at seconds after you, before any notification of any response beeing posted - I tried to post exactly what you posted)

Comment: I wonder why did this thing not worked for you.. i have been working for some complex queries and it was some place i got stuck. Thanks.

Comment: @FlorinGhita Interesting, I did not know SO checked duplicate answers